Create a measure for max of sum of count each week spanning 52 weeks in Power BI
How to create a measure where it calculates in a dataset called "table" the max of sum of count each week spanning the previous 52 weeks given the end date of the week of each row(count = 1) in Power BI? The week column is date format. I want to be able to filter by other columns so that the measured mentioned can dynamically change with the selected column in a slicer in a report. The count column is 1 for each row used for summing.
so far, I have this, but it gave me the same total across each row in a table visual, instead of dynamically changing.
MaxWeeklySum_Last52Weeks = 
VAR CurrentWeekEnd = MAX(table[mmwrendwk])
VAR StartDate = CurrentWeekEnd - 364 -- 52 weeks * 7 days
VAR Last52WeeksData = 
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(table),
        table[mmwrendwk] >= StartDate &&
        table[mmwrendwk] <= CurrentWeekEnd
    )
VAR WeeklySums = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        Last52WeeksData,
        table[mmwrendwk],
        "WeeklySum", SUM(table[Count])
    )
RETURN
    MAXX(WeeklySums, [WeeklySum])

